# IE and jQuery AJAX Requests - Timeout Not Working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I am running into an issue where I am querying a ashx generic handler which can take about 30 seconds to return json results.  If I run my code using Chrome, it works correctly and my grid is populated.  Unfortunately, using IE, it fails with an timeout error.  Even if I set the timeout setting in the ajax request, it doesn't seem to respect it and continues to fail.  Any help or thoughts would be great, thanks.

Wade

Comment: @Wade73, also some code of yours will be appreciated, so we can help you.

Comment: Is the service itself timing out?

Comment: @ScottE No, I reviewed the call in Fiddler and it shows a json result and a 200 Result code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found the issue.  Apparently, there is a registry edit setting - HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet that was causing the connection to close after 10 seconds.  Here is the original link - [Internet Explorer 8 timeout too quick on page POSTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625650/internet-explorer-8-timeout-too-quick-on-page-posts)

Wade