# How to delete a registry value?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I delete a registry value ? I have tried to add the `deletevalue` flag to my `[Registry]` entry but after executing the setup, the value gets re-created.

Can anyone show me how to delete a registry value ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inno Setup: Removing a problematic registry key left by another program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19600188/inno-setup-removing-a-problematic-registry-key-left-by-another-program)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19600188/960757). Except using `deletevalue` I've needed to specify `none` value for the `ValueType` parameter of my `[Registry]` entry. So, something like this:

```
[Registry]
Root:  HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Audit"; ValueName: "MyValueName"; ValueType: none; Flags: deletevalue;
```

Comment: On 64 bits architecture, you have to use HKLM64 instead of HKLM