# Writing 32/64-bit specific registry key at the end of the installation in Inno Setup

Tags: registry, installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to create an installer with Inno Setup, my first time using this tool.
What I’m trying to do is wrapping an existing installer of an existing software with a more detailed self-made installer (meaning a Setup.exe inside a Setup.exe).

What works for me after researching so far is asking the installer (Inno Setup *.exe) to run the included installer (actual software setup).
Why do I need another installer wrapped around? Because I want to give it some extra functions.

On particular thing is: **I want to add a registry-key at the end of my installation, as the last step, fitting for relevant bit-system (32/64-bit).** And here is where I'm asking expert-help, please. (main concern)

My problems in detail are as follows:

1. I managed to add the key using the `[Registry]` section of Inno Setup. However, `[Registry]` seems to always run before `[Run]` – but I need the key added after the installation (added in a regedit-path the installation itself creates), not before, so I deleted what already worked (just in the wrong order) under `[Registry]`. For accomplishing a reg-add after the main-install, I found the two procedures `AfterInstall` and `CurStepChanged`/`ssPostInstall`, and `DeinitializeSetup` which seems not to fit so well for my concern (but thinking `AfterInstall` would be what I'm looking for(?!) since nothing more is supposed to come after and I think it won't run, if the install before already failed (?!).
2. I don't know the Pascal-Syntax for adding a registry-key (string) under an existing path. I could add it under `[Registry]`, however when it comes to the `[Code]`-section I feel a little lost even I did a lot of research by now about Inno Setup given functions and such.
3. Third problem is that the path in the registry differs, depending on whether it's 32- or 64-bit System. So I actually need an extra query here checking the bit-System before adding either one or another path/key (because the install of the program itself creates the path depending on the bit-version already), I found the function `IsWin64` (Boolean), now trying to mix a function (bit-version-query) with a procedure (`AfterInstall`) sounds even for me as a beginner wrong. Plus I tried to create an if-else-query, and the compiler told me I was doing it wrong. `if IsWin64 then...` works, but adding an else doesn't.

So the solution *in theory* would roughly be something like…

```pascal
procedure MyAfterInstall();  
  function IsWin64: Boolean;  
      if 64-bit Reg-Add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\A
      else Reg-Add HKLM\SOFTWARE\B
```

Sorry for not having to offer you more. I am not usually coding.

If relevant, that's what I have in my code-section so far:

```pascal
[Code]
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  RegWriteStringValue(
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\A', 'ConnectionString ', 'Data Source=Test;');
end;
```

Reason why I used `DeinitializeSetup` was because it's one thing that worked for me so far, however I know that this function is called even if the user exits setup before anything is installed, which is not so good. I am running this after the install because the software-installation itself creates the path I want to add the key to, it makes no sense to have the key while the software install failed… Maybe there is a better way for that, too.
Apologies for many words, and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To execute a code after an installation finishes, use the [`CurStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged) and check for `CurStep = ssPostInstall`.

As Inno Setup is 32-bit application, by default it automatically [gets redirected to the `Wow6432Node` on 64-bit systems](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls). No need to do that explicitly. So if the `Wow6432Node` is the only difference between the 32-bit and 64-bit path, you do not to do anything special:

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    Log('Installation finished, writing connection string');
    RegWriteStringValue(
      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\A', 'ConnectionString', 'Data Source=Test;');
  end;
end;
```

Of course, unless you use [64-bit installation mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).

See also: [Writing 32/64-bit specific registry key in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46258689/850848).

---

If the key path really differs, use the [`IsWin64` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_iswin64):

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    if IsWin64 then
    begin
      Log('Installation finished, writing 64-bit connection string');
      RegWriteStringValue(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\A', 'ConnectionString', 'Data Source=Test;');
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Installation finished, writing 32-bit connection string');
      RegWriteStringValue(
        HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\B', 'ConnectionString', 'Data Source=Test;');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Oh my god, it finally worked. Can't believe how much time I spent... Thank you very much. (Also thanks for editting / fixing above, I tend to say too much.) Well, I made this difference between the two bit-versions because the main installation does when creating the registry-path & data records, and I only wanted to add one more string to that. Maybe I just lacked a basic understanding here.

Comment: Also, don't forget the `HKLM64` const. see http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setupcmdline