# Writing 32/64-bit specific registry key in Inno Setup

Tags: registry, inno-setup

I want when I install program, the setup will create the registry in: `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Publisher\App` with `{app}` main location on 64-bit systems. And I want do same for 32bit in "32 bit" location but i don't know where it is. The setup will check version of Windows and create registry depending on the system.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to write to:

- on 64-bit systems: `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`
- on 32-bit systems: `SOFTWARE`

For that, you do not need to do anything special. [Windows registry redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/registry-redirector) handles that. It automatically redirects `SOFTWARE` to `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` for 32-bit applications running on 64-bit systems. And Inno Setup installers are 32-bit applications.

So a simple `[Registry]` section entry like below will do, what you want. No need for any 32-bit or 64-bit specific code:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\My Company\My Program\Settings"; ...
```

Of course, unless you use [64-bit installation mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).

---

See also [Writing 32/64-bit specific registry key at the end of the installation in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41677819/850848).

Comment: Okay. Now i understand. Thanks for answer.